# return statement in JavaScript used without breaking out of the function

Tags: javascript, logic

Is there any possible method in which the control in a JavaScript function can be retained even after a return statement is executed?

The following paraphrased example will explain my requirement:

#### Called function:

```
function tree(node) {
    if (node == 'root') {
        return true;
        // this return needs to be executed on IF condition 
        // being true and then continue executing the remaining 
        // statements of function as a requirement.
    }
    
    do_something;
    // this does some 
    // visualization changes and has to be 
    // after the IF statement. 
}
```

The Above example is not the exact implementation, but that is the logic I require to implement.

#### The Calling statements are something like this:

```
var fact = tree(n);
if (fact == 'true') {
    count++;
}
```

I am looking for any solution that would retain control within the function even after a return for various reasons which is too much to explain over here. Any alternative logic is also welcome :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the last part to be executed asynchronously you can try the setTimeout method.

```
function tree(n){
    //do stuff before return

    //execute something parallel to returning
    async(function(){do_something;}));

    return...
}
function async (fn) {
    setTimeout(fn, 20);
}
```

Comment: Thanks.. this is an feasible alternative. :)

Answer (score 0):

No, then the remaining statement outside the if statement won't be executed.  Do *always return at the end of the function like*

```
function tree(node) {
  var stat; //create a local variable within tree method
  if(node=='root') {
    stat = true; //assign true to stat inside if
   }
   do_something;  //this function gets executed
   return stat; //now return it while exiting the method
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Define a result variable and do the return at the very end of your function:

```
function tree(node){
  var result; // kind of a cached result

  if(node=='root') {
    result = true; // set the result
  }

  do_something;

  return result; // return the result
}
```

When using a `return`-statement, you are leaving the function context in any case. So the only way to remain inside the function, is to delay the return statement to the end of the function (or at least after your other code has run).